# How do you find the orthographic projection of a convex polyhedron with maximum or minimum area?

Tags: polygon, projection, orthographic, polyhedra

An orthographic projection of a convex polyhedron has an outline which is a convex polygon whose shape depends on the projection direction. How do you choose the direction to maximise or minimise the area of this polygon?